# Change content of share button

Tags: javascript, facebook, plugins, twitter, share

So I use this share-button plug-in for twitter and face-book.
However, I don't understand what I should change to get my URL and my title when pressing the buttons. plz help.

Html:

```
<a onclick="Share.facebook('URL','TITLE','IMG_PATH','DESC')"> {sharing is sexy}</a>
<a onclick="Share.twitter('URL','TITLE')"> {sharing is sexy}</a>
```

JS:

```
Share = {
    facebook: function(purl, ptitle, pimg, text) {
        url = 'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100';
        url += '&p[title]=' + encodeURIComponent(ptitle);
        url += '&p[summary]=' + encodeURIComponent(text);
        url += '&p[url]=' + encodeURIComponent(purl);
        url += '&p[images][0]=' + encodeURIComponent(pimg);
        Share.popup(url);
    },
    twitter: function(purl, ptitle) {
        url = 'http://twitter.com/share?';
        url += 'text=' + encodeURIComponent(ptitle);
        url += '&url=' + encodeURIComponent(purl);
        url += '&counturl=' + encodeURIComponent(purl);
        Share.popup(url);
    },
    popup: function(url) {
        window.open(url,'','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626, height=436');
    }
};
```

The plug-in can be found at: http://www.webdesign.org/html-and-css/tutorials/how-to-create-a-share-button-for-your-site.22180.html

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.href` will give you the page's URL, and `document.getElementsByTagName("title")` will give you the page's title element.

Does that answer your question, or are you looking to set these values at the exact time the buttons are pressed?

Comment: I found the answer my self, it was quite obvious, you just change the 'TITLE' in the <a> tag to what ever you wanted. My problem was that i used an `'` within the tag, so it went haywire :P Thanks anyways ;)